# What is the difference between a sharepoint site page and web page

Tags: 2013

What is the difference between a sharepoint site page and web page. In site contents I have the ability to create the page under site page or web page?   Im looking for a good explanation between the too.

Answer (score 3):

There are two primary types of pages in Microsoft SharePoint Foundation. They are **site pages** and **application pages**. The following topic will discuss the differences between the two types of pages. Application and site pages both inherit their layout from the same master page.

**Site pages** are pages that are created, edited, and customized by end users. They are primarily used for the content in a site. Site pages come in two types—a standard page and a Web Parts page. A standard page contains text, images, Web Parts, and other elements. A Web Parts page contains Web Parts in Web Part zones. They have a predefined layout that uses Web Part zones. Both types of site pages are edited using a Web browser or Microsoft SharePoint Designer.

**Application pages** are used to support application implementations in SharePoint Foundation. Application pages are stored on the file system of the front-end Web server in the %ProgramFiles%\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\web server extensions\14\TEMPLATE\LAYOUTS directory and exist for every site in a Web application. This folder is mapped to an Internet Information Services (IIS) virtual directory called _layouts. Every site and subsite will have access to the application pages by using the _layouts virtual directory.

[SharePoint Page Types](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa979592(v=office.14).aspx)

[Introduction to sites, workspaces, and pages](https://support.office.com/en-au/article/Introduction-to-sites-workspaces-and-pages-db309204-cf0a-43a4-8481-ac65f64fa497)
http://www.mcgladreyconsultingpros.com/sharepoint-create-page-vs-sub-site/

Answer (score 0):

Anything you can do in Sharepoint can also be done in a web page.  Think of sharepoint as a web page template that can be applied across the organization.